# Check if specific words exist in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of keywords, which are stored in a spreadsheet and then converted into a dataframe with a single column "keywords". I am using this dataframe to check whether the keywords stored in it exist in text in a different dataframe ("text dataframe").

```
 1) keywords dataframe

     keywords

  1   ice cream
  2   ice cone 
  3     truck
  4   Ice cream truck


 2) text dataframe


       text

  1  ice cream truck just arrived 
  2  can I have some ice?
  3  Ice quickly melts
```

What I currently have is this function to check whether only specific keywords/phrases exist in the text dataframe

```
def check_keyword():

    keyword = text_dataframe[(text_dataframe.text.apply(lambda x: any(term in x for term in keywords_dataframe['keywords'])))]

    if len(keyword) == 0:
          return pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], index=[])
    else:
          return keyword
```

However, the problem is that the check_keyword function also flags sentences which contain words that I don't want to flag. For example instead of flagging exact phrases only ("ice cream", "ice cone" etc.) it also flags words "ice" and "Ice". What is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first matched keyword:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in keywords_dataframe['keywords'])
text_dataframe['flag'] = (text_dataframe['text'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
                                .fillna('no match'))

print (text_dataframe)
                           text       flag
1  ice cream truck just arrived  ice cream
2          can I have some ice?   no match
3             Ice quickly melts   no match
```